# How do I run 640x480 only games in Wine properly?

Tags: wine, games, display-resolution

Whenever I try to play a 4:3 game like Chicken Invaders, my system goes into 4:3 and the game window appears in the top left corner. This means it is incredibly annoying to try and play the game and I have to kill Wine to get back to 1080p. The Chicken Invaders appdb has no information on how to fix this and I couldn't find any results on my search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command `winecfg` from Terminal. In the Wine Configuration window- click on **Graphics** tab, check the option **Emulate a virtual desktop.** Now input your native display resolution in the boxes under that option. Click Apply and then Ok.

Comment: In addition, you can also selectively launch a particular application in a virtual desktop via the command [wine explorer /desktop=name,1024x768 program.exe](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_get_Wine_to_launch_an_application_in_a_virtual_desktop.3F).